# How to determine `isReady` for Firebase/Admob interstitial Ad

Tags: firebase, admob, cocos2d-x

For iOS, admob comes with `isReady` field to determine if ad is ready to be shown. Now I am integrating Admob to my Android game in cocos2d-x and i am following this official guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/cpp/quick-start#set_up_an_interstitial_ad

```
if (interstitial_ad->LoadAdLastResult().status() ==
    firebase::kFutureStatusComplete &&
    interstitial_ad->LoadAdLastResult().error() ==
    firebase::admob::kAdMobErrorNone) {
  interstitial_ad->Show();
}
```

The condition is slightly different from the iOS `isReady` API. After an ad is already shown, for iOS, `isReady` will be false. But `LoadAdLastResult` is still `Complete` even after ad is shown. I need something similar to `isReady` to decide if I need to request a new ad. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this logic by yourself. For example: a variable (interstitialAdShown), which indicates that you need to request a new ad

```
  // Set up the show interstitial ad button.
  showInterstitialAdBtn = createButton(false, kShowInterstitialText);
  showInterstitialAdBtn->addTouchEventListener(
      [&](Ref* sender, cocos2d::ui::Widget::TouchEventType type) {
        cocos2d::ui::Button* button = static_cast<cocos2d::ui::Button*>(sender);
        switch (type) {
          case cocos2d::ui::Widget::TouchEventType::ENDED:
            // The show intersitial button is enabled in the update() method
            // when the interstial ad has successfully loaded. Here the show
            // interstitial button has been pressed by the user, so we disable
            // the button and display the interstitial ad to the user.
            button->setEnabled(false);
            logMessage("Showing the interstitial ad.");
            interstitialAd->Show();
            // Invalidate all Futures and enable loadInterstitialAdBtn.
            interstitialAdShown = true;
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      });
this->addChild(showInterstitialAdBtn);
```

You can look at full sample here - https://github.com/firebase/cocos2dx-cpp-sample/blob/master/admob/Classes/FirebaseAdMobScene.cpp#L441

Other firebase examples for cocos2d-x from google - https://github.com/firebase/cocos2dx-cpp-sample

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know for IOS and Android the behavior is quite similar in terms of interstitial loading.

In Android you use this to check if interstitial is ready to show:

```
if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
```

Further more for Android good practice is to request new interstitial ad in the onAdClosed event